# Deploying a Visual Studio 2015 C++ App from Windows 10 to Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-c++, deployment, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 installed on Windows 10 (Pro edition) and I am using this to develop a C++ app. This app runs as intended on the development computer. However it will not run properly on either of two laptops. One of these machines is Windows 7 Home Premium.

On each of the non-development machines, when the executable is double-clicked the first time, three instances of the process open instead of one. Successive attempts to open any VC2015 executable from my computer each result in a single new process. These processes do not open a console window, are unresponsive and cannot be killed even using Process Explorer or Process Hacker.

I have tried creating a new empty project, adding one file called "main.cpp" and typing the following into it:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "output string\n\n";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

The same thing happens. This demonstrates that the issue is not due to a third-party library dependency.

I have also tried:

- Installing the Visual C++ 2015 Redist (x86) on the target machine.
- Making sure the x86 Release configuration is selected in Visual Studio.
- Using the /MT flag to link statically.

Comment: One of my collegues met the same problem on Windows 7 system with third-party software. After several attempts to fix the situation he reinstalled operating system. After this the problem disappeared.

Comment: Did he reinstall Windows 7 on the development machine?

I am using official versions of Windows and Visual Studio.

Comment: No, he reinstalled OS on target machine. Because this software was developed by third-party company

Comment: Avast antivirus was the problem on my laptop. I have to confirm tomorrow that my friend also has the same AV.